# No such host is known.(calling weatherAPI from webapi controller using HttpClient)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to call the openWeatherApi from asp.net WebAPI. When I receive the name of a city from front-end, I use that to lookup the city/airport from the database. Then, I use the lat and long of the airport to call the openweather API. I want to use the response to make further calculations and predictions.

My code is:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

try
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweather.org");
                     var response = await client.GetAsync($"/data/2.5/weather?lat={airport.AirportLatitude}&lon={airport.AirportLongitude}&appid={apiKey}");
                  //  var response = await // client.GetAsync($"/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid={apiKey}");
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var rawWeather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenWeatherResponse>(stringResult);
                    System.Console.WriteLine("$$$$$$$$$$$After API call made$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
                    System.Console.WriteLine(response);
                    return Ok(new {
                        Temp = rawWeather.Main.Temp,
                        Summary = string.Join(",", rawWeather.Weather.Select(x=>x.Main)),
                        City = rawWeather.Name
                    });
                    // return Ok(response);
                }

                catch(HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
                {   
                    System.Console.WriteLine(httpRequestException.Message); 
                    return BadRequest($"Error getting weather : {httpRequestException.Message}");
                }
```

When I run this app, sometimes I get 400BadRequest, and other times I get 500:Internal Server Error

1) No such host is known.
2) System.InvalidOperationException: This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<HttpClient>(); 
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

When I try to put the complete openweather url in my browser, it returns json, but it gives error when trying to run from ASP.NET CORE Web Api Controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use the `using` statement

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
          try
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweather.org");
                 var response = await client.GetAsync($"/data/2.5/weather?lat={airport.AirportLatitude}&lon={airport.AirportLongitude}&appid={apiKey}");
              //  var response = await // client.GetAsync($"/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid={apiKey}");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var rawWeather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenWeatherResponse>(stringResult);
                System.Console.WriteLine("$$$$$$$$$$$After API call made$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
                System.Console.WriteLine(response);
                return Ok(new {
                    Temp = rawWeather.Main.Temp,
                    Summary = string.Join(",", rawWeather.Weather.Select(x=>x.Main)),
                    City = rawWeather.Name
                });
                // return Ok(response);
            }

            catch(HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
            {   
                System.Console.WriteLine(httpRequestException.Message); 
                return BadRequest($"Error getting weather : {httpRequestException.Message}");
            }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that before coming up with the above code.

Comment: This is wrong - you should *never* wrap `HttpClient` in a `using` block - it could lead to port exhaustion. In ASP.NET Core, they have a factory for this; in a desktop application, you should use the same instance in a Singleton.

Comment: The correct mechanism for managing `HttpClient` in ASP.NET Core can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) - the way shown here is dangerously wrong, especially for an API with a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is wrong and dangerous - you should never wrap a `HttpClient` in a `using` block because it can lead to port exhaustion during heavy use.

For more details on this, you can see this Microsoft-endorsed blog post: [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Also, from [this article from Microsoft](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/09/using-http.aspx),

> There's a very good chance that, every time you need to access a Web Service, you've been creating an HttpClient object and then throwing it away. **Unfortunately, that's bad for your application because you can run out of WebSockets (yes, even if you call the object's Dispose method before discarding it).** Though, I have to admit, you'll only have this problem if you use the HttpClient a lot. Still, it's a bad idea to keep creating and destroying it.
>
> **In the .NET Framework, the intent was for you to create the HttpClient once in your application and use it over and over.** To do that you'll have to declare your HttpClient object as a global or static variable. That creates its own problems, of course.
>
> **In ASP.NET Core, however, you have a better option: the HttpClientFactory.** The HttpClientFactory provides you with HttpClient objects but takes responsibility for managing the resources that the clients can use up. Think of it as "connection pooling for Web Services."

So, in a desktop application, use `HttpClient` as a public static variable or wrap it in a Singleton. In an ASP.NET Core application, use [the built-in factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to create your `HttpClient` instances.